# Passing 2D array from inner project to View as a table in MVC C#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Im not sure How could I do this :

I have this method in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult outputTable() {

                DataSet dat = new DataSet();
                dat.calc();
                table = dat.table; // table is type of string[,]
                for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(1); col++) {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(table[row, col] + " ");


                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                }
}
```

And I would like to print this array in this format but in the view as the table.

Output in VS is like this :

```
18 0 0 
18 42 18 
0 0 12
```

The problem is that I can assign as ViewBag variable only 1D array. 
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your can use this viewModel

```
public class sampleModel
{
    public int[,] Array{set;get;}

}
```

then on your controller bind it like below

```
 var model = new sampleModel
 {
     Array = new int[table.GetLength(0),table.GetLength(1)] 
 };

 for (int i = 0; i <table.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j <table.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
         model.Array[i, j] = table[i, j];
     }
 }
 return View(model);
```

**Edit :**

on your view side you can do this

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for(int j=0;j<Model.Array.GetLength(1);j++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Model.Array[i, j]
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but how should the view look like?

Comment: I did what u adviced but keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

The problem is that my ActionResult method actually contains a view and I just want to add to this view the table.